# Подключение к WMI по локальной сети

Tags: wmi

ip основного ос (windows 11) 192.168.56.1

ip ос на virtual box (windows xp) 192.168.56.101

подключение осуществляется через virtualbox host only ethernet.
На windows xp я отключил брэндмауэр. через основную ос виртуальная пигнуется, а наоборот нет.
и когда я пытаюсь подключиться к WMI виртуальной ос выскакивает ошибка.
помогите советом, может кто сталкивался с таким
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *через основную ос виртуальная пигнуется, а наоборот нет* Что получаешь - timeout? файрвол на хосте, скорее всего. *когда я пытаюсь подключиться к WMI виртуальной ос выскакивает ошибка* опять же файрвол плюс вообще разрешения на RPC и прочее необходимое.